# Control for displaying gif in a WP7 silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, gif

I'm trying to display gifs in a WP7 silverlight application.

I've seen this project : http://imagetools.codeplex.com , but it seems not able to display all kind of gifs.

Do you know other controls that can display all gifs ? Even third party control ?

Thanks in advance for any help

[Edit:]
for example, I would like to display this gif :
[image]

but it doesn't work.
Although with this one : http://ec.europa.eu/culture/media/programme/images/logos/02/02.gif17.gif it's working

(The image were found by googling, I hope I'm not violating anything)

Comment: Are you trying to display an animated gif?

Comment: How is this question different to when you asked it before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152564/display-gif-in-a-wp7-application-with-silverlight

Comment: @Matt: its true this question isn't well asked in comparison with the other question.  Perhaps Tim should have spent more words on emphasising the phrase __all kind of gifs__.   Its the _all kinds_ bit which causes this question to vary from the last and hence is not really an identical question IMO.

Comment: Hi Tim, if you know, it may help if you can be specific with some examples of the types of GIFs you want support for that would resolve your question in contrast to what the codeplex project doesn't support.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, you're. I can display some gif, but not all. That's what I want. And I'm ready to buy third party control if needed...

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight for WP7 does not include the necessary codec(s) for displaying gifs.

You should convert the images to a supported format (PNG or JPG). If at all possible don't to this conversion in the app.