# WP7: Creating a movie from bitmap images

Tags: windows-phone-7, movie, animated-gif, bitmapimage

I'm developing a WP7 app. I have a collection of BitmapImages that I load from the isolated storage.

Now I want to make a movie or animated GIF from those BitmapImages, is this possible? And if yes how?

An animated GIF is probably not possible because Silverlight does not work with gifs.

Comment: but it does work with pngs which can have an animation too

Answer (score 0):

Yes Windows Phone 7 doesn't support animated GIFs. Here's a link to something similar that might be able to help you though:

[Display GIFs in a Windows Phone 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152564/display-gif-in-a-wp7-application-with-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of images in isolated storage I'm guessing that you don't want to turn them into an animated gif on the phone anyway.

Just use a Timer to cycle through the images.
If you want greater control over the "playback" you could create an actual movie file but whether this is practical will depend on the images and how you get them into IS in the first place.

Comment: For phone purpose i use a timer to cycle. But i would like to add a sharing function for Facebook and YouTube, and then i need to make a video out of it.

Comment: @Preben H If these are custom images on the phone, I'd move the generation of the video off the device and onto a backend server. You'll have more processing power and resources there, not to mention access to the full framework and additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

Using story board would be a good idea to create an animation. But the problem is how to export the animation. I have been thinking a solution for a long time.