# WP7 Listbox & gif binding

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

My .xaml like this

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="90" Height="90" Source="{Binding ImgUri}" Name="codeimage"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I've already convert a .gif to writeableBitmap.
But have no idea how to bind writeableBitmap
with listbox.

Can anyone give my some hint please?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

If you're binding the path of an image to a Uri which is a gif you'll have to apply a converter to manage the conversion to a supported format (png of jpg).

Have a look at [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152564/display-gif-in-a-wp7-application-with-silverlight/4152866#4152866).

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the response. But I still not very clear. Is any there any simple pseudocode?

Comment: @scchun I've updated my answer in light of the updated question.