# How to test file-type of URL in PHP?

Tags: php, image, file-type

I'm trying to download an image from a URL, and if it's a gif, I'm going to convert it, and otherwise, I'm going to just leave it as it is. However, much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203811/how-to-display-a-gif-image-in-windows-phone-7) (it's actually to solve the same problem), I have URLs that don't contain file extensions, so I need to somehow determine the file-type another way.

What's the best way to do this? Using headers would probably be easy, but since I know the URL will have to involve a redirect before I can actually access the file, I'm not sure the best way to test it?

Comment: you could try the fileinfo pcl extension maybe? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php

Comment: I think you want [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

Comment: I tried to use finfo_file, but it throws an error "Failed identify data 0:(null)" when I use a full url as the filename.

Comment: Why are you wanting to know before it gets to your server? Get it, store it temporarily or whatnot, figure out if it's `gif` or not, convert if necessary, and be done with it. You're going to get the file anyways, right?

Comment: The way I see it is, from an efficiency standpoint, downloading every file to test isn't very good when only a few are going to need to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send a request to the URL, follow any returned redirects (your HTTP client should do that for you), then read the `Content-Type` header.
Note that the header cannot be trusted; a malicious server or proxy can set any header it wants.

Comment: Would the server set the header though if the extension is missing?

Comment: This seems to be working for now, so I think I'll go with that. in_array("Content-Type: image/gif",get_headers($url));

Comment: Also, since the headers are coming from a single website that I trust, I'm not worrying too much about fake headers.

Comment: @Ben: That depends on the server.