# Why .gif image shows only some first frames(Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

my previous question with source code is here: [How to use gif animated image in WP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667840/how-to-use-gif-animated-image-in-wp-7)

I am using http://imagetools.codeplex.com/
in my animated gif I have 24 frames, but it decodes only some first frames, so I see repetition animation of some(maybe two) frames again and again

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use an animated .gif with silverlight? Especially on a phone? Why not just create your image animation with a Storyboard in xaml and add it via a ContentControl or something?

Comment: @Chris W.: revolutionkpi's animated GIF is a detailed rotating globe of the world. Probably way too inefficient for practical use, but an interesting problem to solve all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some gif-files this decoder work, for some other - don't.

I downloaded source code of that project and found the code which doesn't work correctly. It is situated in the `ImageTools.IO.Gif\GifDecoder.cs` file, the `Decode` method:

```
int nextFlag = stream.ReadByte();
while (nextFlag != 0)
{
    //...
}
```

But [this gif](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif) contains the 0 byte right in the middle, so that the decoder stops where it shouldn't. The solution is to change this flag to -1 so that we are sure that the gif image will be read to the end:

```
int nextFlag = stream.ReadByte();
while (nextFlag != -1)
{
}
```

So you need either to recompile this library or to include the `ImageTools.IO.Gif` project in the form of source code rather than in the form of dll.

You can download the sample project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/StackOverflow/TestGif.zip

But I'm not sure that one can rely on this fix. Anyway I opened the issue at [codeplex](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/workitem/10510).