# Is there any limitation for number of frames used for gif image in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I am currently using 25 frames gif Image and i am not able to see the whole gif content. part of it is missing. Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you displaying the animated gif? There's no built-in support in WP7. Are you using a WebBrowser component, or another library?

Comment: Windows Phone does not support GIF format

Comment: string GIFUrl = "Images/HowItWorksGIF.gif";
           
            ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
            ImageTools.ExtendedImage image = new ImageTools.ExtendedImage();
            image.UriSource = new Uri(GIFUrl, UriKind.Relative);
            HowItWorksGIFimage.Source = image;

Comment: For displaying GIF image I am using the above code

Comment: Does this question relate to the same issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671646/why-gif-image-shows-only-some-first-frameswindows-phone