# Windows Phone 7.1 "png" image not loading from URL

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I get the result from Web service as XML format. I have read it and hold it List<> then bind to ListBox control (Windows Phone 7.1)

I get image path in URL as below

http://latam.zed.com/MCP/Estilos/352/7406_BannerWap_2012103_92241.png

Above image not loading(this img is animated type)

My Code as below: I try many ways but Not success.

```
var TopVentasNew = from c in TopVentas.Descendants("content_item")

            select new clsContent
            {
              id = c.Element("id").Value,
              image_url = c.Element("image_url").Value

            };                      
ListBox1.ItemsSource = TopVentasNew.ToList<clsContent>();
```

Plz help me, how can I load Animated type of png image in WP7.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So is there a problem with your binding? do non-animated PNGs work? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hey, non animated images load properly. work fine. But animated type of image not loaded. I get 10 images, 9 images are loaded properly, but above img not loaded. This img load work fine. http://latam.zed.com/MCP/Estilos/352/7545_BannerWap_20121025_124343.png

Comment: How big are your image? Be aware of the size limitation.

Comment: Dimension is 350 X 52 And Size will be 14/16 KB

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any source at the moment but I think Windows Phone and Silverlight don't support Animated PNGs.

What you can do is look at [this library](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/). I know it adds support for animated GIF on Windows Phone. More info here : [Display GIF in a WP7 application with Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152564/display-gif-in-a-wp7-application-with-silverlight)

Comment: thanks man, I will look the Image tool. let's see how it help me. :)

Comment: Animated type of image not loaded in "Imagetool" :(