# Why I can not display this picture by a Image Control?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, xaml

When I debug my Windows Phone app (7.5 and above)

I can use a browser to see this picture : http://xiciimgs.xici.net/d178542377.0/123_s.jpg

But when I use this xaml, I just can't see anything via the emulator or the real phone.

```
<Image Source="http://xiciimgs.xici.net/d178542377.0/123_s.jpg">
</Image>
```

why and how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try with your desktop or emulator/phone browser? Your emulator/phone may not be connected to the internet.

Comment: I test on my phone, it has a internet connection

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure your image is visible and not covered entirely by another control within a grid for example? Try make an empty page with nothing but the image and see what happens.

Comment: can not see it either, when I change the image source to something else, i can see it.

Comment: try dummy test. get instance of "WebClient" and try download data and see if phone/emulator is able to download this image. if positive try to set image source from code. If it works I cannot imagine what went wrong with this XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like your JPG file is actually encoded as a GIF. So your problem mitgh be resolve here: [Display GIF in a WP7 application with Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152564/display-gif-in-a-wp7-application-with-silverlight)

Or if you have access to this image, you could convert it in JPG.

Hope it helps.