# how to display the gif image in windows phone by not using web browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, gif

how to show the gif image in windows phone 7, i tried from many site, but they have done only by using web browser to view the gif image. now i want to view the gif image by not using of web browser control, usually have to view the gif image as jpeg image in windows phone 7. how to do Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

u cant render directly the gif image in wp7 & so u can decode it to the bitmap image to show

ther are many links to show how to convert gif into bitmap, take a look at these--->

[Display GIF in a WP7 application with Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152564/display-gif-in-a-wp7-application-with-silverlight)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/23/working-with-gif-images-in-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: i want to show animated image shows as well from gif format only , can u tell me any demo project link?

Comment: <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <imagetools:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

Comment: <imagetools:AnimatedImage  Source="{Binding ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Margin="9,22,158,104" /> ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
            ImageSource = new Uri( "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m90uismbPw1r244l5o1_400.gif", UriKind.Absolute );
            this.DataContext = this;

Comment: but not working.. pls help me anybody is there another way to solve this problem..

Comment: iam getting exception of type Image.Tools.IO.IImageDecoder is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. you must add a reference to assembly "ImageTools, version = 1.0.0.0, culture=natural, publicKeyToken=null"